# AudioRecord object not initializing

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

In the below code my `audioRecord` object is not initializing. I tried moving it to the `onCreate` method and made it a global. I've logged the state and that returns a value of `1` which means ready to use. The debugger says that `startRecording` is being called on an uninitialized object. It is also saying that it could not get the audio source.

Why am I getting these errors?

```
    package com.tecmark;

    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.AudioFormat;
    import android.media.AudioRecord;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class recorder extends Activity  {

        private Thread thread;
        private boolean isRecording;
        private AudioRecord recorder;
        private FileOutputStream os;
        private BufferedOutputStream bos;
        private DataOutputStream dos;
        private TextView text;
        private int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
        private int sampleRate = 22050;
        private int channel = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
        private int encoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        private int result = 0;
        private int bufferSize;
        private byte[] buffer;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Log.v("onCreate", "layout set, about to init audiorec obj");
            text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

             bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,channel,encoding);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            recorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate,channel,encoding,
                    AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channel,encoding));
            Log.i("recorder obj state",""+recorder.getRecordingState());
        }

        public void onClickPlay(View v){

        }


        public void record(){
            Log.i("inside record method", "******");
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.v("file path", ""+path.getAbsolutePath());

            File file = new File(path, "test.wav");

            if(file.exists()){
            file.delete();
            }

            path.mkdirs();
            Log.v("file path", ""+file.getAbsolutePath());

            try {
             os = new FileOutputStream(file);
             bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);            
                 dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);        
            } catch (Exception e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,channel,encoding);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            recorder.startRecording();
            isRecording = true; 
            try{  
                while (isRecording){
            result = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            for(int a=0; a<result;a++){
                 dos.write(buffer[a]);

                 if(!isRecording){
                   recorder.stop();          
                   break;
                 }

            }

             }
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }// end of record method

    public void onClickStop(View v){
        Log.v("onClickStop", "stop clicked");
        isRecording=false;
    }   
    public void onClickReverse(View v){
        Log.v("onClickReverse", "reverse clicked");
    } 
    public void onClickRecord(View v){
        Log.v("onClickRecourd", "record clicked, thread gona start");
        text.setText("recording");
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                isRecording = true;
                record();
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        isRecording = false;
    }   
}//end of class
```

**Logcat**

```
01-30 15:23:16.724: ERROR/AudioRecord(12817): Could not get audio input for record source 1 01-30 15:23:16.729: 
ERROR/AudioRecord-JNI(12817): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed. 01-30 15:23:16.729: 
ERROR/AudioRecord-Java(12817): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code
-20 when initializing native AudioRecord object. 01-30 15:23:16.729: INFO/recorder obj state(12817): 1 01-30 15:23:16.729: 
WARN/dalvikvm(12817): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b180) 01-30 15:23:16.729: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12817): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-7 exiting due to uncaught exception 01-30 15:23:16.739: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12817): java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord. 01-30 15:23:16.739: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12817):     at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:495) 01-30 15:23:16.739: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12817):     at com.tecmark.recorder.record(recorder.java:114) 01-30 15:23:16.739: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12817):     at com.tecmark.recorder$1.run(recorder.java:175) 01-30 15:23:16.739: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12817):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: use recorder.getState() to get the correct state

Comment: After rebooting my device (which the mic itself is not working after I tried on wrong initialization setting, so to check whether one has entered a blackhole or not, testing with microphone will be an easy one), then i tried on the try-all-the-combination initialization method and it works!
thanks!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The trick with using AudioRecord is that each device may have different initialization settings, so you will have to create a method that loops over all possible combinations of bit rates, encoding, etc.

```
private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT }) {
            for (short channelConfig : new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO }) {
                try {
                    Log.d(C.TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                            + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                            return recorder;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(C.TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

AudioRecord recorder = findAudioRecord();
recorder.release();
```

Comment: ^^^ this.  I had to crawl through the Android source code to figure this out myself.

Comment: This isn't going to work as well as you think because some Android devices will enter a Black Hole of Hell if you use an unsupported sample rate. The only way to get the microphone to work again is to reboot the device.

Comment: I've also had similar experiences, Kevin (but haven't had to reboot before) -- the audio system on Android can be different on all the various devices and can behave very differently depending on the version/device, recover differently, etc.  Guess it just has to be a 'guest guess/effort.

Comment: Used this with galaxy S5 and S6 after clean restarts with RECORD_AUDIO permission on a sample app that supposedly works; everything was either Invalid audio format (as you'd probably expect) or a repeat of the same error as the OP (Could not get audio input for record source 1).

Comment: Might be an idea to change bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE into bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE && bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR (consider: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioRecord.java#553)

Comment: I ran this code and it got the same error on every attempt. Also added the permission to the manifest. Also restarted the device. Also did clean build.

Answer (score 92):

I had the same issue, it was solved by putting

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

into the manifest.

Since Lollipop, you also need to specifically ask the user for each permission. As they may have revoked them. Make sure the permission is granted.

Comment: just a note for newcomers, in Android 6 Marshmallow, I also have to manually enable the permission for the app: https://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/

Comment: Actually @SeanZhu comment worked for me. I spent 4 hours in the middle of night. By the way it has been 24 hours since I started learning Android development.

Answer (score 10):

According to the javadocs, all devices are guaranteed to support this format (for recording):

44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT.

Change to CHANNEL_OUT_MONO for playback.

Comment: Yes, but a lot of devices really don't.

Comment: Yes docs are wrong on this. Super low end phones tend not to support this.

Comment: is this still holding true or is it a standard?

Answer (score 4):

Problem with initializing few AudioRecord objects could by fixed by using `audioRecord.release();` before creating next object...
More here: [Android AudioRecord - Won't Initialize 2nd time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139739/android-audiorecord-wont-initialize-2nd-time)

Answer (score 4):

Now, with lollipop, you need to specifically ask the user for each permission. Make sure the permission is granted.

Answer (score 4):

Even after doing all of the above steps I was getting the same issue, what worked for me was that my **os was marshmallow and I had to ask for permissions**.

Comment: Mind sharing the permissions that worked for you (almost a year later...) I'm using RECORD_AUDIO and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem.
The solution was to restart the device. While playing with the code I did not release the AudioRecord Object which obviously caused the audio device to stuck.
To test whether the audio device worked or not I downloaded Audalyzer from Google Play.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I knew it had to be the device and not the code because I didn't change anything between a working build and a broken one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your mobile phone system is Android M or above,perhaps you need to apply record audio permission in Android M.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

in my case I had to manually allow the permission in android 7 for microphone, as sean zhu commented.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when the SDCard on the avd I am running gets full the AudioRecord constructor returns null.  Have you tried clearing the SDCard?

Comment: thanks.. buddy.. after clearing the SDcard.. my problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the thread not knowing that you've paused the main activity and still trying to record after you've stopped the recorder.

I solved it by changing my onResume() and onPause() methods to modify the isRecording boolean.

```
public void onResume() { 
    ... 
    isRecording = true;
}

public void onPause() { 
    ... 
    isRecording = false;
}
```

Then in your thread, surround both your `startRecording()` and `stop()` with if-statements checking for isRecording:

```
if(isRecording) 
    recorder.startRecording();
...
if(isRecording)
    recorder.stop(); // which you've done
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the answer from @DustinB for anyone who is using Xamarin Android AudioRecord with C#.

```
int[] sampleRates = new int[] { 44100, 22050, 11025, 8000 };
Encoding[] encodings = new Encoding[] { Encoding.Pcm8bit, Encoding.Pcm16bit };
ChannelIn[] channelConfigs = new ChannelIn[]{ ChannelIn.Mono, ChannelIn.Stereo };

//Not all of the formats are supported on each device
foreach (int sampleRate in sampleRates) 
{
    foreach (Encoding encoding in encodings) 
    {
        foreach (ChannelIn channelConfig in channelConfigs) 
        {
            try 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting rate " + sampleRate + "Hz, bits: " + encoding + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.GetMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, encoding);

                if (bufferSize > 0) 
                {
                    // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic, sampleRate, channelConfig, encoding, bufferSize);

                    if (recorder.State == State.Initialized)
                    {
                        mBufferSize = bufferSize;
                        mSampleRate = sampleRate;
                        mChannelConfig = channelConfig;
                        mEncoding = encoding;
                        recorder.Release();
                        recorder = null;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sampleRate + "Exception, keep trying." + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```