# AudioRecord can not be initialized

Tags: android, voice-recording, android-audiorecord

I am trying to work with audiorecorder, but I am getting illegal argument exceptions stating that the audiorecorder is not initialised.

My code is like the one shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/AudioRecorder.2/src/com/varma/samples/audiorecorder/RecorderActivity.java)

```
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,  RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);                        
recorder.startRecording();
```

I have seen another answer which seems to work for some people but it isn't working for me 
[AudioRecord object not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing)

Comment: have you done this ?  AudioRecord recorder = null;

Comment: yes I did while making it a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private void startRecording() {
        String fileSaveName = generateNameForAudioFile();
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileSaveName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }



private void stopRecording() {
        startRecording.setEnabled(true);
        try {
            if (mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

public String generateNameForAudioFile() {

        String audioName = GetrandFilename();
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"
                + audioName + "myaudio" + ".3gp";

        );
        return mFileName;
    }



@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

            try {
                if (mRecorder != null) {
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
              }
```

Let me know if this post is of any help.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have already tried that and was successful but the sound quality was really very poor in some devices so I am trying the same with audiorecord

Answer (score 0):

I was actually doing the silly thing I was giving the permissions inside application tag corrected it and it's working fine thanks everyone for the time and support