# AudioRecord: start() status -38

Tags: android, audiorecord

I have the following problem:
I use SpeechRecognizer to identify a few words.
I use the

```
public void onResults
```

method to destroy the SpeechRecognizer.

Right after the destruction I initialize an AudioRecord and start recording from the mic. 
This leads to the following error in my logcat:

```
12-09 00:44:01.976: E/AudioRecord(21185): start() status -38
```

No exception is thrown in my code. The AudioRecord just does not start properly.
I am assuming that the SpeechRecognizer does not release the microphone quickly enough,
because if I add a Thread.sleep(200) in front of the initialization of the AudioRecord, I
do not experience this issue.

This solution is very bad for obvious reasons. Thus, I have the following question:

How do I check whether the AudioRecord is initialized properly? (I do not get an exception in my code.)

```
_audioRecord.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED
```

is false as well.

Or how do I check whether SpeechRecognizer released the microphone properly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about checking if `getRecordingState()` equals `RECORDSTATE_RECORDING` ?

Comment: Thanks, completely overlooked that one.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make sure you issue `audioRecord.stop();` and `audioRecord.release();` in your `onPause()` or similar methods. If you don't, the next time you run the app, you won't get access to the device, and you'll get `start() status -38`

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem to this [AudioRecord start() error status -38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204693/audiorecord-start-error-status-38)
what i eventually did was loop over the possible configurations of the audio recorder like the answerer said in this question
[AudioRecord object not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing)
I like this method since it doesn't matter what device you run it on it will eventually find a configuration that it likes.

Comment: Hi, my for loop always chooses 16000 as a samplerate, but AudioRecord initializes properly only the first time. What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

I checked recording state by using `audioRecord.getRecordingState()` as Michael commented.
Normally after `audioRecord.startRecording();`, recordingState becomes RECORDSTATE_RECORDING.
If state is not RECORDSTATE_RECORDING, I will close app.

```
audioRecord.startRecording();
int recordingState = audioRecord.getRecordingState();
Log.i(VoiceRecorder.class.getSimpleName(), "RecordingState() after startRecording() = " + String.valueOf(recordingState));
if (recordingState != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
    Log.i(VoiceRecorder.class.getSimpleName(), "AudioRecord error has occured. Reopen app.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a different app that was probably running the background and didn't release the recording device. You also need to make sure all other apps are closed (using the switch between apps > CLEAR ALL).