# AudioRecord start() error status -38

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I'm trying to set up an audio recorder and I keep getting a specific error and I can't figure out why. in my code I have checked what state the audio recorder is in with the Log before and after the startrecording() method.

```
ar = new AudioRecord(audiosource, sampleRate, channelConfiguration,
                audioEncoding, buffersizebytes);
Log.d("info", "ar.getState() before = " + String.valueOf(ar.getState()));
ar.startRecording();
Log.d("info", "ar.getState() after = " +String.valueOf(ar.getState()));
```

When I run the app I'm getting these messages in logcat.

```
D/info﹕ ar.getState() before = 1
E/AudioRecord﹕ start() status -38
D/info﹕ ar.getState() after = 1
```

from what I have read in the documentation the state 1 can either correspond to the audio recorder being in the RECORDSTATE_STOPPED or the STATE_INITIALIZED states neither of these two should cause a problem when calling startRecording().

The status -38 I believe is a errno.h code for  /* Function not implemented */ is this referring to the startRecording() method or as it states in the error the start() function which is not a method for the AudioRecorder class.

I have tried multiple methods to make sure that the release() function was called so I don't think that is the problem here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/audioBoom/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/BooRecorder.java  check out a robust android recorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright so this is what i think i needed to do this should really be talked about in the AudioRecorder documentation but this similar questioin led me to the answer [AudioRecord object not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing)
basically what you want to do is loop through all the configurations and try each against the AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE check also since I was planning on using a fft in which the length must be a power of 2 i added a little if else if portion if anybody else runs into a similar situation

```
public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT}) {
            for (short channelConfig : new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                try {
                    //Log.d("audioSetup", "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                    if (bufferSize > 0 && bufferSize <= 256){
                        bufferSize = 256;
                    }else if (bufferSize > 256 && bufferSize <= 512){
                        bufferSize = 512;
                    }else if (bufferSize > 512 && bufferSize <= 1024){
                        bufferSize = 1024;
                    }else if (bufferSize > 1024 && bufferSize <= 2048){
                        bufferSize = 2048;
                    }else if (bufferSize > 2048 && bufferSize <= 4096){
                        bufferSize = 4096;
                    }else if (bufferSize > 4096 && bufferSize <= 8192){
                        bufferSize = 8192;
                    }else if (bufferSize > 8192 && bufferSize <= 16384){
                        bufferSize = 16384;
                    }else{
                        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                    }

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                            Log.d("found", "rate: " + rate + " channelConfig: " + channelConfig + " bufferSize: " + bufferSize + " audioFormat: " + audioFormat);
                            sampleRate = rate;
                            channelConfiguration = channelConfig;
                            audioEncoding = audioFormat;
                            buffersizebytes = bufferSize;
                            return recorder;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("audioSetup", rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

seems to work nicely. thanks for the help.

Comment: You can eliminate the long if..else chain.

    `int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
    if(minBufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE && minBufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR) {
      int bufferSize = 256;
      while(bufferSize < minBufferSize) bufferSize <<= 1;
      AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord();
      // ...
    }` (Sorry about formatting.)