# java.lang.AssertionError: Expected condition to be true webrtc android

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

I am implementing webrtc in android using libjingle (version-9127), the issue is that in one application life cycle when I try to make calls, then the first call is successfully established and then ended. But when second call is made then when the call gets pickup then , the video is displayed , but audio stream is not transferred and then after 3-7 sec the app crashes giving this error.
The complete logcat error is below:

```
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioRecordJni: BuiltInAECIsAvailable@[tid=23918]
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioManager: SetCommunicationMode(1)@[tid=23918]
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioManager: setCommunicationMode(true)@[name=Thread-1692 - 23918, id=1699]
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioRecordJni: InitRecording@[tid=23918]
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: InitRecording(sampleRate=48000, channels=1)
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioRecordJni: OnCacheDirectBufferAddress
08-25 13:47:12.099 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioRecordJni: direct buffer capacity: 960
08-25 13:47:12.109 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize: 4096
08-25 13:47:12.109 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: bufferSizeInBytes: 4096
08-25 13:47:12.109 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecord session ID: 299, audio format: 2, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000
08-25 13:47:12.109 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable: false
08-25 13:47:12.129 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioRecordJni: frames_per_buffer: 480
08-25 13:47:12.129 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/AudioRecordJni: StartRecording@[tid=23918]
08-25 13:47:12.129 20887-23918/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: StartRecording
08-25 13:47:12.159 20887-24120/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecordThread@[name=AudioRecordJavaThread, id=1707]
08-25 13:47:12.159 20887-24120/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
08-25 13:47:12.159 20887-24120/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app W/dalvikvm: threadid=41: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41687d58)
08-25 13:47:15.232 20887-24120/com.justtotaltech.tagove.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AudioRecordJavaThread

                 Process: com.justtotaltech.tagove.app, PID: 20887
                          java.lang.AssertionError: Expected condition to be true
                          at org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioRecord.assertTrue(WebRtcAudioRecord.java:259)
                          at org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioRecord.access$300(WebRtcAudioRecord.java:29)
                          at org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioRecord$AudioRecordThread.run(WebRtcAudioRecord.java:79)
```

**Edit**: To disconnect the call I have made this code. Hope you can figur out what the error is. After this I am releasing peerConnections

```
if(mediaStream != null  && isLocal) {

        mediaStream.removeTrack(audioTrack);
        audioTrack.setState(MediaStreamTrack.State.ENDED);
        audioTrack = null;
        audioSource = null;

        if(videoTrack != null && ActivityCall.callTypeGlobal.equals(CallManager.CallType.VIDEO)){
            Log.d("TestCallType",String.valueOf(ActivityCall.callTypeGlobal));
            mediaStream.removeTrack(videoTrack);
            videoTrack = null;

            source.stop();

            videoCapturer.dispose();
            videoCapturer = null;
            activeCamera = null;
            Log.d("TestCallType","Video Track"+String.valueOf(videoTrack));
            Log.d("TestCallType","Video Capturer"+String.valueOf(videoCapturer));
        }

        mediaStream = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/openpeer/webrtc/blob/master/webrtc/modules/audio_device/android/java/src/org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioRecord.java) (if that's not the repository i'm sure that's the class that you're using based on the error lines numbers) the line that causes the exception is this:

`assertTrue(audioRecord.getRecordingState()
          == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)`

Make sure to release everything you use after a call finishes. When a new call starts every resource needs to be fresh. And initialize all back again.

Comment: @AkshayBissa I have basically the same code so I don't know any other steps

Comment: @SamuelMéndez I am using MediaPlayer to play the ringtone can that also be issue for dis

Comment: Seeing the log the first error is `AudioRecord start() status -38`. There are some questions about that topic (like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460892/audiorecord-start-status-38). Maybe the solution comes from that

Comment: @SamuelMéndez No, this was not useful. 
Can you provide me what is the complete process to disconnect the call in webrtc

Comment: @abissa I am working with the same problem. Could you please assist me that how did you solve your problem? Thanks.