# Android AudioRecord cannot find working configuration

Tags: android, case-sensitive, android-permissions, audiorecord

I am trying to buffer audio data to analyze the decibel level.

I am using the AudioRecord class, since it allows to process the data right away from a buffer without storing them in a file.

I am using the

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

permission. ***Edit***: This is wrong!

I am launching it as a service from my main activity in `onStart()` with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Audio2.class);
startService(intent);
```

The service calls `findAudioRecord()` during `onStartCommand(...)`.

```
private int[] sampleRates = new int[] { 44_100, 22_050, 11_025, 8_000 };
private short[] audioFormats = new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT };
private short[] channelConfigs = new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO };

public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : sampleRates){
        for (short audioFormat : audioFormats){
            for (short channelConfig : channelConfigs){
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, " + audioFormat + " bits, channel: " + channelConfig);
                    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize*10);

                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                            return recorder;
                        } else {
                            recorder.release();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.wtf(TAG, "No working configuration found!");
    return null;
}
```

This allways returns null. I get the error:

```
E/AudioRecord﹕ AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
E/AudioRecord-Java﹕ android.media.AudioRecord Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4.

What I have tried without success:

- restarted the device several times
- tried it on a GT-S6790N
- tried it on an emulated device
- [AudioRecord object not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing) Tried everything in this post (and every related post in any form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hours, I finally figured out the problem. If you use the autocomplete feature of Android Studio and type

```
<uses-permission android:name="RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

followed by enter, Android Studio will fill in

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

This, however does not work, since case apparently matters. No warnings, nothing. After I changed it to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

it finally worked...