# AudioRecord object not initializing in a project

Tags: java, android, sampling

When I am trying to record an audio through my Nexus 5 using following code

```
record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, BYTE_OF_SAMPLE * bufferSampleSize);
record.startRecording();
```

Then I am getting following exceptions in logcat:

```
E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-855
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.*.*, PID: 14206
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:885)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.*.*.MainActivity$Looper.run(MainActivity.java:265)
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9e476d00
```

I've added following line in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I've tested [AudioRecord object not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing). None of those solutions working.

But its working in another project. 
Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the solution:
Recently I updated my phone to Marshmallow. In Marshmallow there is a new permission system. I switched on these permissions as bellow the recording works just fine.

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly my issue!

Comment: Do all my users have to go into the settings and allow this manually? Can't I do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for recording. find the complete code from here [Android Audio recording example](https://gist.github.com/chathudan/95d9acdd741b2a577483)

```
private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000);
    } else {
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
    }
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
    mOutputFile = getOutputFile();
    mOutputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTickExecutor, 100);
        Log.d("Voice Recorder","started recording to "+mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Voice Recorder", "prepare() failed "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: Android Audio recording]

Comment: I can't use MediaRecorder as I need to read audio samples to create spectrum analyzer.