# Android - Failed to Initialize an AudioRecord for All Possible Combinations of Arguments

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I'm using the code below find an available combination of params to create an `AudioRecord` object.

```
public static AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : new int[]{8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100}) {
        for (int audioFormat : new int[]{
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_AC3,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_E_AC3,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_DTS,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_DTS_HD,
        }) {
            for (int channelConfig : new int[]{
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_LEFT,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_RIGHT,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_FRONT,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_BACK,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_LEFT_PROCESSED,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_RIGHT_PROCESSED,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_FRONT_PROCESSED,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_BACK_PROCESSED,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_PRESSURE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_X_AXIS,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_Y_AXIS,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_Z_AXIS,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_VOICE_UPLINK,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_VOICE_DNLINK,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                            + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                            return recorder;
                        }
                        recorder.release();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the function always returns `null`, with no available params found. **Most combinations pass the `bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE` condition check, but get `false` for `recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED`.**

I have tried to reboot my device (MOTO X2), but it didn't work.

I have declared the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission, and below is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.gowear">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".RecordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_record"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is the debug log:

```
03-08 20:48:58.080 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.091 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.092 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.092 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.093 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.096 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.097 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.097 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.097 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.101 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.102 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.102 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.102 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.105 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.106 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.106 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.106 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.109 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.110 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.110 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.110 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.114 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.115 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.115 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.115 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 1, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.115 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.115 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0, channelMask 0x10; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.115 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 1, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0 channelMask c
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0, channelMask 0xc; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 1, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0, channelMask 0x10; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 5, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0x9000000 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0x9000000, channelMask 0x10; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 5, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0x9000000 channelMask c
03-08 20:48:58.116 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0x9000000, channelMask 0xc; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 5, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0x9000000 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0x9000000, channelMask 0x10; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 6, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0xa000000 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0xa000000, channelMask 0x10; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 6, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0xa000000 channelMask c
03-08 20:48:58.117 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0xa000000, channelMask 0xc; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.118 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 6, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.118 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 8000 format 0xa000000 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.118 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 8000, format 0xa000000, channelMask 0x10; status -22
03-08 20:48:58.118 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 4, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.121 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.123 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.123 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.123 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 4, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.126 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.127 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.127 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.127 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 4, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.133 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.134 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.134 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.134 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.137 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.138 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.138 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.139 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.141 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.149 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.149 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.149 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.152 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.154 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.154 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.154 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.157 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.159 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.159 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.159 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
03-08 20:48:58.161 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.163 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.163 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.163 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 1
03-08 20:48:58.166 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
03-08 20:48:58.167 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
03-08 20:48:58.167 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-08 20:48:58.167 12250-12250/com.example.gowear D/Recorder: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 1, channel: 16
03-08 20:48:58.168 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioSystem: AudioSystem::getInputBufferSize failed sampleRate 11025 format 0 channelMask 10
03-08 20:48:58.168 12250-12250/com.example.gowear E/AudioRecord: AudioSystem could not query the input buffer size for sampleRate 11025, format 0, channelMask 0x10; status -22
```

...

I have read lots of similar questions but none of them could fix my problem. Is there any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: What version is your Android?

Comment: @mapm Android 6.0 on Moto new X.

Comment: Since you version is Marshmallow one possible solution could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33625836/4924260

Comment: @mapm Oh, thank you! I forgot this!

Comment: Did it resolve your problem?

Comment: @mapm Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so my solution was, if you are using the Marshmallow version there is a new permission system. To allow the permissions in your device do this steps:

1. Go to "Application manager" as follow "Settings->Applications->Application manager".
2. Locate your application a select it to get the "Application info".
3. If the permissions options shows ["No permissions allowed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1z48.png) then tap on it to [switch on these permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjcak.png). This will allow your app to run fine.