# <AudioRecord> Could not get audio input for record source 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, audiorecord

I am trying to get AudioRecord instance but I get errors:

> Could not get audio input for record source 1
>
> Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
>
> Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class AudioCapturer {
    AudioRecord recorder;
    private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private static final int AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;
    private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRates[3], channelConfig, audioFormat);


    protected void Start() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, mSampleRates[3], channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
                    Log.v("RECORDER","" +recorder.getState());
                    recorder.startRecording();

                    while(recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)
                    {
                        byte [] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        Log.v("READ RESULT","" + recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length));
                    }
                }
            }).start();
    }
}
```

I've added permissions but result is still the same.
My mobile phone API version is 18.

Comment: Are you sure about the API version and the permissions? Sounds like a known problem. Please add your permission and build gradle code

Comment: Yes I am. I put into AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you can solve the issue changing

```
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
```

to

```
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
```

Better solution would be to loop through all possible parameter values combinations to select working combination. See [AudioRecord object not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing)

Comment: Result is still the same. I've checked it on other Android versions, it works on Android 7.0 but not on 4.3

Comment: Did you try to test different combinations of parameters?