# How to enable audio recording in Android emulator?

Tags: android

I've found several answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972022/188826) one) that tell it is possible to record audio in Android Emulator. But I didn't succeed in finding any suitable setting in Android Virtual Device Manager and I still get an exception on the line `recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the documentation of [`MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) you can see that:

> **Note:** Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator.

Even in the last API.

But I saw that in the class [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), there is no note for this.
More then that, I have found this code:

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 500000);
recorder.startRecording();
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169939/1725836). And the code's author said that this code works in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can record the audio by executing:

`adb emu avd hostmicon`

Reference:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator

Answer (score 0):

found this

> You guys are not able to record sound in emulator because the android
>   emulator doesn’t support it yet. This code should only work on the
>   phone.

a [Source](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

Comment: I also found this article. But it is 5 years old while the answer I reference in the topic was created two years after that. And the guy in the answer describes some very specific settings which wouldn't exist if Android Emulator didn't support Audio Recording. The problem is that I didn't find those settings.

Comment: Also Note: The Android Emulator does not have the ability to capture audio, but actual devices are likely to provide these capabilities.   [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)

Comment: It is pretty much the same answer. The problem is that I can not find Android SDK and AVD Manager. I have SDK Manager and AVD Manager installed but can not find Android SDK and AVD Manager